# Bokeh DataTable datetimeformatter

Tags: bokeh, datetime-format

I am calling a function to create DataTable - the problem is Date field has both Date and Time in the same column and is not getting displayed properly.I will prefer to keep the field Date + Time values intact - however can separate it into two different fields of Data and Time if its not possible.

```
def make_table(source):
columns = [
    TableColumn(field='DATE', title="DATE", formatter=DateFormatter()),
    TableColumn(field='CCYPAIR', title="CCYPAIR"),
    TableColumn(field='SIDE', title="SIDE"),
    TableColumn(field='PRICE', title="PRICE"),
    TableColumn(field='TYPE', title="TYPE"),
    TableColumn(field='Volume', title="Amount"),
    TableColumn(field='ORDER_ID_108', title="ORDERID"),
 ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=1000, height=400)
return data_table
```

CCYPAIR                    DATE ORDER_ID_108   PRICE SIDE   TYPE    Volume

0  EURCHF 2015-01-15 13:41:34.555      380      1.2    B  ORDER      50.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below change makes it working.Thanks

```
string_dates = []
for i in df['DATE']: string_dates.append(i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
df['DATE'] = string_dates
```